# Can you change the mouse focus?

Tags: mouse, lxterminal

I'm reading  book about the command line and it mentions that some OS's had an option to change from having to click the mouse to focus on a window to receive input and having to just scroll over the window for it to be able to receive input. Are you able to do this in Raspbian? I have looked in `sudo raspi-config` but did not see any options for anything like this.

Comment: It's a setting in the Display Manager. I can currently not look at it.

Comment: @ott Where is the Display Manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the OS (and also not the Display Manager) which has that option, but the Window Manager — the program which renders the frames around windows and its title bar. (At least in the Unix/Linux/BSD world that's independent of the OS.)

Raspbian uses LXDE as default desktop environment which itself uses by default the OpenBox window manager. The OpenBox window manager can be configured using the `obconf` command. (I'm not sure if it is installed by default. If not, use "apt-get install obconf" to install it.)

If you start `obconf` and choose the *Mouse* tab, there is a checkbox labeled

> Focus windows when the mouse pointer moves over them

Enabling this feature should get you what you want.